# Retrieve "templated" items of an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, itemscontrol, contentcontrol

I'm currently doing a custom panel in UWP.

I've the following xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ForTest}"  
    SizeChanged="OnFluidPaneSizeChanged" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel>
                <wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel.ElementEasing>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.35"></BackEase>
                </wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel.ElementEasing>
                <wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel.DragEasing>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.65"></BackEase>
                </wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel.DragEasing>
            </wpfSpark:FluidWrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
        <Button Margin="10" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                SomeButton
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'm listening on the `SizeChanged`, I managed to get my panel:

```
FluidWrapPanel fwPanel = itemsControl.ItemsPanelRoot as FluidWrapPanel;
```

I can also get the items:

```
fwPanel.FluidItems
```

but thoses are `ContentControl`.

I've to change the `Width`and `Height` of every items generated, so how can I end by setting this size to every button?

Comment: I checked, but it seems I've only the "current Item" of my ObservableCollection named ForTest(in my case it's just a string)

Comment: Sorry, I confused that.

Comment: Binding width and height to button and change the  value in code behind?

Comment: @Archana Binding to what? Because my datacontext is set to my ViewModel, and this is only to handle a View stuf, so having it in code behind doesn't bother me

Comment: If you have width and height property for each item in viewmodel you can change it easily I feel

Comment: @J4N can you explain what is your expectation? Do you want the button will change its size according to the size of the ItemsControl's panel? please try to explain us what are you trying to do step by step.

Comment: @Ilan I've a FluidPanel, and basically, depending on the available space, I decide of the layout(rows x columns). When it's done, I want to set the size to match exactly one cell

Comment: @J4N Is this happened inside the OnFluidPaneSizeChanged handler?

Comment: @Ilan Yes it is. The author of the FluidPane told me it should work

Comment: And since I've to retrieve one element(the first) to know it's "minWidth/minHeight", in order to compute the Width/Height, I don't think I can just "bind" it